# How to pass a enum variable to a struct with template specialization for enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums, constexpr

I design a struct  with template specialization for enum, like this:

```
template<DataType type>
struct TypeTrait;

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_INT8> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(int8_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_INT16> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(int16_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_FP16> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(uint16_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_UINT8> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(uint8_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_UINT16> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(uint16_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_INT32> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(int32_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_UINT32> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(uint32_t);
};

template<>
struct TypeTrait<DATA_TYPE_FP32> {
    static constexpr uint32_t size = sizeof(float);
};
```

enum DataType is defined like this:

```
enum DataType {
    DATA_TYPE_INT8 = 0,
    DATA_TYPE_INT16 = 1,
    DATA_TYPE_FP16 = 2,
    DATA_TYPE_UINT8 = 3,
    DATA_TYPE_UINT16 = 4,
    DATA_TYPE_INT32 = 5,
    DATA_TYPE_UINT32 = 6,
    DATA_TYPE_FP32 = 7,
    DATA_TYPE_UNKOWN
};
```

And I want pass a DataType variable to struct TypeTrait, like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    ...

    void Convert() {
        ...
        uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type_>::size;
        ...
    }
private:
    DataType type_;
};
```

When I do this, there is a problem while compiling my program:

```
main.cc: In member function ‘void Test::Convert()’:
main.cc:63:35: error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression
   63 |         uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type_>::size;
      |                                   ^~~~~
main.cc:63:40: error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression
   63 |         uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type_>::size;
      |                                        ^
main.cc:63:35: note: in template argument for type ‘DataType’
   63 |         uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type_>::size;
      |                                   ^~~~~                              ^
```

I tried many ways, like convert `type_` to be a const value, like this:

```
const DataType dataType = type_;
uint32_t size = TypeTrait<dataType>::size;
```

Then this problem arosed.

```
main.cc: In member function ‘void Test::Convert()’:
main.cc:63:39: error: the value of ‘type’ is not usable in a constant expression
   63 |         uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type>::size;
      |                                       ^
main.cc:62:24: note: ‘type’ was not initialized with a constant expression
   62 |         const DataType type = GetType();
      |                        ^~~~
main.cc:63:39: note: in template argument for type ‘DataType’
   63 |         uint32_t size = TypeTrait<type>::size;
      |
```

I know the program will be no problem if I pass enum element like this.

```
uint32_t size = TypeTrait<DataType::DATA_TYPE_UINT32>::size;
```

I have no idea to solve this issue. So I must use switch case to handle this, which is against my wishes.
I just want to remove the switch case in my codes.
The code to be refactored:

```
    switch (dataType_) {
        case DATA_TYPE_INT8:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(int8_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_INT16:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(int16_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_FP16:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(uint16_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_UINT8:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(uint8_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_UINT16:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(uint16_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_INT32:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(int32_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_UINT32:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(uint32_t);
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE_FP32:
            byteSize = elemCnt * sizeof(float);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Remove "C" tag, since this is obviously a "C++" only question

Comment: I recommend replacing the whole specialisation thing with an constant array indexed by DataType.

Comment: you are mixing compile-time concepts with runtime concepts. `DataType type_;` is a member whose value is only known at runtime (even const does not change that) while the template argument must be known at compile time

Comment: is it an option to parametrize `Test` on the enum value? Ie `template <DataType dt> struct Test { ...` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I cannot change the class Test to template <DataType dt> struct Test because this class is unmodifiable for me.  Sorry, I am mixing compile-time concepts with runtime concepts. So is there any other way to do this without using switch case?

Comment: how to do with an constant array indexed by DataType.  @n.m.willseey'allonReddit

Comment: "because this class is unmodifiable for me"  then its not possible to use the members value as argument for the template

Comment: `std::array sizes{ sizeof(int8_t), sizeof(int16_t) ...}` then use `sizes[type_]` instead of the trait

Comment: OK , I see.  Using constant array  may be a good methd.  So I must give up the way to use the members value as argument for the template.Thanks a lot.  @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Comment: *"give up the way to use the members value as argument for the template"* You mean you think this would stop the result from being a compile-time constant? It wouldn't, you just need to make the array `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to fetch the `TypeTrait<type>::size` at runtime without a switch (C++17 required):

```
uint32_t datatypeSize(DataType type) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return ((static_cast<std::size_t>(type) == Is ? TypeTrait<static_cast<DataType>(Is)>::size : 0) + ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<DATA_TYPE_UNKOWN>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Er9Y4Mzea)

Another, using `std::array` (from Jarod42's comment - C++17 as well):

```
uint32_t datatypeSize(DataType type) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array{TypeTrait<static_cast<DataType>(Is)>::size...}[type];
    }(std::make_index_sequence<DATA_TYPE_UNKOWN>{});
}
```

Comment: or `return std::array{TypeTrait<static_cast<DataType>(Is)>::size...}[type];`.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's nice. A shame it's a comment instead of an answer, though.

Comment: You might add it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add another answer without using template specialization.
I think this implementation is more convenient and concise

```
#define DefineHelper(XX)\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_INT8, sizeof(int8_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_INT16, sizeof(int16_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_FP16, sizeof(uint16_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_UINT8, sizeof(uint8_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_UINT16, sizeof(uint16_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")\
  XX(DATA_TYPE_INT32, sizeof(int32_t), "DATA_TYPE_FP32")

int32_t GetDataTypeSize(DataType e){ 
#define TypeSize(e, n, _) case e: return n;

  switch(e) {
    DefineHelper(TypeSize)
    default:
      return 0;
  }
#undef TypeSize
}

const char* GetDataTypeStr(DataType e) {
#define TypeStr(e, _, s) case e: return s;
  switch(e)
  {
    DefineHelper(TypeStr)
    default:
      return "unknowntype";
  }
#undef TypeStr
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  DataType type = static_cast<DataType>(atoi(argv[1]));
  printf("typesize:%d desc:%s\n", 
         GetDataTypeSize(type), GetDataTypeStr(type));
  return 0;
}
```